# How do I get a unique css selector of a BeautifulSoup object?

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup

I want to get a unique css selector path of an element in an HTML.

I'm using BeautifulSoup but cannot figure out how to really get a unique css selector like you would using Chrome dev tool.

Say, you're trying to get a unique css selector of an element in Google's page - specifically, `Gmail` button on the top right. Using Chrome's dev tool, you can easily use 'copy selector' and get: `#gbw > div > div > div.gb_9d.gb_i.gb_yg.gb_pg > div:nth-child(1) > a`

I'm trying to do the same thing without knowing any prior information about the website structure. i.e, from a single BeautifulSoup element.

I tried to get a unique selector by listing all parents of the element but that is NOT unique. I need something more like class & id to really make it unique

How do I pull this off?

(Of course it works in very simple cases like the one I gave you below but css selector path only using the tag names is always in danger of not being unique.)

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

html = urlopen("https://www.google.com")
html_bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

gmail = html_bs.find_all(text='Gmail')[0]
print(type(gmail)) # >> bs4.element.NavigableString

# How do I get gmail's unique css path?

# I tried to use parents but this is generally not unique. 
# div > div > nobr > a might NOT be unique in some cases. 

for parent in gmail.parents:
    print(parent.name)
# >>
'''
a
nobr
div
div
body
html
[document]
'''
```

Comment: unique selector usually means single `id` or `class`. For something longer you may have to use `select()` (or `xpath` in other modules) instead of `find()`

Comment: @furas I'm trying to get a css selector from an element, not the other way around. Usually people get an element from css selector but I'm trying to get a css selector from the element I found with `find()`.

I tried `.selector()` but it says `AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'selector' `

Comment: BS doesn't have function to get selector.

Comment: @furas That's a bummer.... Any other way to get it though?

Comment: I don't know. I usually build selector manually using data from DevTools in Chrome/Firefox

Comment: you can get the attribute of tags with `.attrs`. Might not work in this case because the page is likely dynamic, but try changing your `print` to `print(parent.name, parent.attrs)` might get you closer to what you are looking for

Comment: using your `for`-loop you could create some selector but in some situations it still would need index `[0]`,`[1]`,etc. to make it unique - and it could be more complicated.

Comment: So I guess there's no built-in solution for this. I also thought of building my own function using `.attrs` but I just wanted to check if there was a ready-made solution for this to prevent from reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Here's what I've got from Reddit. The guy gave me a link to the source code of FireFox's css selector and it seems fairly simple.
https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/emrla9/how_do_i_get_a_unique_css_selector_of_a/